# How to I make a for/if loop that compares multiple rows and prints timestamps

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp, data-science

I am currently trying to develop a code that compares the data within rows. The objective of the program is to make a comparison between the difference in speed and if there is a big difference in speed, I would like for it to print the timestamp. Here is what I wrote so far:

```
for row in cj1:
speed = row[1].speed
timestamp = row[0].timestamp
for i in range(1, row.length):
if speed is different =!:
      Calculate acceleration
if acceleration > #certain amount:
   print(timestamp)
Else:
   timestamp = rows[i].timestamp
   speed = rows[i].speed
```

It is a really rough code and I'm not too sure how to express it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Yes I am using Python 3

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to time how long code takes. You can use this context manager example.

```
from time import time, sleep

class Time(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.end = time()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start


with Time() as t:
    sleep(5)  # <- your code here

print(t.interval)
```

---

**5.001040935516357**

**UPDATE**

So you can ask a better question next time. Here is some feedback:

```
for row in cj1:
    speed = row[1].speed                # <- There was no indent here.
    timestamp = row[0].timestamp
    for i in range(1, row.length):
        if speed is different =!:       # <- There was no indent here.
                                        # `=!` with out another value is a syntax error.
              Calculate acceleration    #  <- `Calculate` is not defined.
                                        #  Also no brackets are used,
                                        #  maybe `Calculate(acceleration)`?
        if acceleration > #certain amount:

                                        # `acceleration` is not defined.
                                        # You can not compare greater than with a comment.
           print(timestamp)
        Else:                           # < - `Else` cannot be capitalised. you mean. `else`
           timestamp = rows[i].timestamp
           speed = rows[i].speed
```

Comment: Question is about comparing values from a data object, not about the code speed itself.

Comment: I did my best to help, but your code isn't formatted correctly, and I don't quite understand what you imply with a `data object`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should show a piece of your data, how does it look like?
In which format the values are?
The code you showed has wrong indentations etc.  I suppose that data cannot be read like row[1].speed, or does that really work?

Edit:
Was that Calculate some kind of pseudocode? Please, try to formulate single rows in Python shell first to see that they are python code...

Comment: You should know by now, that comments are not answers. Please read [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Yes, comment would be better. It is a pity, that I'm not allowed to write them.   I think I could modify my answer, if I just would understand what question maker wants do do.